# Android remove multiple instances of same activity except the first

Tags: android, multiple-instances, activity-stack

I saw many threads similar to this. But my scenario is different. This is my `Activity` flow

```
Activity A -> Activity A (optional)('n' times) -> Activity B -> Activity C
```

When I click a button in `Activity` C, I have to go back to First Activity A closing all others on top of it and perform a task there. When I click back button this flow should not be disturbed. I cannot use any **android:launchmode** except **standard** for my scenario. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a boolean instance variable which stores whether an instance of `A` is *first* or not. Than in your `onActivityResult` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == PREVIOUS_CLOSED && !mFirst) {
             setResult(PREVIOUS_CLOSED);
             finish();                
         }

}
```